# Sample Covariance vs. Population Covariance in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am wondering how to use sample covariance in my VBA code.

I can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Covar(array_1,array_2)` to get the population covariance, but how about the sample covariance? I realize that there are `COVARIANCE.S` and `COVARIANCE.`P Functions in the formula bar. How can I use them in my VBA code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xl2010 you can certainly use
`Application.WorksheetFunction.Covariance_P`

`Evaluate` or the shorthand `[]` is your friend for calculating functions

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Covariance_P([a1:a3], [b1:b3])
MsgBox [Covariance.P(a1:a3, b1:b3)]
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! So I just need to use `_` instead of `.`. I also tried the square bracket solution, because it seems really handy. But I failed to get it to work, all it returns Error 2099(If I remember correctly)